# State variable being overwritten

Tags: solidity, storage

When I run the code in remix, The state variable *requesting* is overwritten after a call to *addSimpleStruct()*, which makes it impossible to add another struct because of the require statement. Why would this be and how can I make it so the address in *requesting* persists throughout the contracts entire lifetime.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;


contract test {
  address public requesting;

  struct simpleStruct {
    bytes32 desc;
    uint256 startTime;
  }

  struct itmap
  {
    mapping(bytes32 => IndexValue) data;
    KeyFlag[] keys;
    uint size;
  } 

  struct IndexValue { uint keyIndex; simpleStruct value; }
  struct KeyFlag { bytes32 key; bool deleted; }

  itmap data;

  function test() public {
      requesting = msg.sender;
  }

  function addSimpleStruct(bytes32 key, bytes32 _desc) public { 

    require(msg.sender == requesting); 

    simpleStruct storage newStruct;
    newStruct.desc = _desc; 
    newStruct.startTime = now; 
    insert(data, key, newStruct); 
  }

  function insert(itmap storage self, bytes32 key, simpleStruct storage value) internal returns (bool replaced)
  {
    uint keyIndex = self.data[key].keyIndex;
    self.data[key].value = value;
    if (keyIndex > 0)
      return true;
    else
    {
      keyIndex = self.keys.length++;
      self.data[key].keyIndex = keyIndex + 1;
      self.keys[keyIndex].key = key;
      self.size++;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug.

```
  function addSimpleStruct(bytes32 key, bytes32 _desc) public { 

    require(msg.sender == requesting); 

    simpleStruct storage newStruct; <-----
    newStruct.desc = _desc; 
    newStruct.startTime = now; 
    insert(data, key, newStruct); 
  }
```

If you remove it, and declare in the contract `simpleStruct newStruct`, it will work.

Now, why it doesn't work? Right now, I am trying to understand exactly why, but my first guess, I could be wrong on this one, probably am, but I think since it's written to storage, it's written at slot 0, and "crushes" the value of `requesting`? But I doubt...

Comment: Since newStruct is not initialized it will reference the first slot of storage, which is requesting. So modifying it will override requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Eli and Ismael are exactly right.

This syntax...

`simpleStruct storage newStruct;`

causes an "uninitialized storage pointer" error in 0.5.x compilers. You need to initialize with `=` to set it to *something*, otherwise it will default to slot 0 in memory, which is a horrible thing because it mean overwriting whatever else is there.

This is a confusing and scary topic. Have a look over here: https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089

Hope it helps.